# Objective c/c: Detect USB drive via IOKit only on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, notifications, iokit

Here is my code and it will detect the devices when I run the application at first, but it will not detect the new one after it is running.

```
//Just for testing
 - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
   [self detectUSB];
}

void detectUSB()
{
  //dictionary
  CFMutableDictionaryRef matchingDict = matchingDict = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName);

  //create notification
  IONotificationPortRef notificationObject; //notification object to listen
  mach_port_t masterPort = 0; //received from IOMasterPort
  notificationObject = IONotificationPortCreate(masterPort);

  //create run loop
  CFRunLoopSourceRef notificationRunLoopSource;

  //use notification obejct received from notificationPortCreate
  notificationRunLoopSource = IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource(notificationObject);

  CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), notificationRunLoopSource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);

  IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(notificationObject,kIOFirstMatchNotification, matchingDict,isAttached,(__bridge void*)self,&iter );

  isAttached(NULL, iter);
}

void isAttached(void *refcon, io_iterator_t iterator) {

    io_service_t usbDevice;
    while((usbDevice = IOIteratorNext(iterator))) {
         io_name_t name; 
         IORegistryEntryGetName(usbDevice, name);
         printf("\tName:\t\t%s\n", (char *)name);

         CFNumberRef idProduct = (CFNumberRef)IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty(usbDevice, kIOServicePlane, CFSTR("idProduct"), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
         uint16_t PID;
         CFNumberGetValue(idProduct, kCFNumberSInt16Type, (void *)&PID);
         printf("\tidProduct:\t0x%x\n", PID);

         IOObjectRelease(usbDevice);
         CFRelease(idProduct);
      }
   IOObjectRelease(iterator);
 }
```

What's more, if I unplug one of USB drive, how should I detect that ? Should I add one more

```
  IOServiceAddMatchingNotification(notificationObject,kIOFirstMatchNotification, matchingDict,isDetached,(__bridge void*)self,&iter );
```

after isAttached function? Actually I added but it gives me bad access error. Could you guys tell me how to handle these problems? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies with the `IOObjectRelease()` call in your handler function. You need to hold on to the iterator that you get from the `IOServiceAddMatchingNotification` for as long as you want to receive these notifications. If you remove the release call, the code works.

As for your second question: the call gives a bad access error, because `matchingDict` gets released by `IOServiceAddMatchingNotification`. If you do a `CFRetain(matchingDict)` before that call, you can add a second Notification using the same matching dictionary. (BTW: you should pass `kIOTerminatedNotification` instead of `kIOFirstMatchNotification` if you are interested in device removal notifications.

Comment: BTW: you also need to add two different source to runloop.